# Получить разрешение экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

два телефона - Android OS, HD, FHD экраны. Высота 720+1080  соответственно.   Теперь проблема:

```
alert(window.screen.availHeight);
alert(window.screen.height);
alert(screen.height);
//640
//640
//640
```

Браузеры - сток, хром. Мне надо чтоб телефоны с экраном разрешением менее 720 пикcелей по высоте НЕ выполняли сценарий js. Что делать?
UPD: в эмуляторе мобильного в хроме цифры честные

Comment: пробовал использовать window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight или document.documentElement.clientWidth/document.documentElement.clientHeight? эти вещи привязываются к размеру окна браузера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли про такое понятие как соотношение пикселя (`window.devicePixelRatio`), попробуйте так:

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var w = screen.width * ratio;
var h = screen.height * ratio;
```

***Пример:***

```js
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var w = screen.width * ratio;
var h = screen.height * ratio;
alert(screen.width);
alert(screen.height);
alert(w);
alert(h);
```

[Полезная ссылка.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml)